# Excluding dependencies from classpath for TestNG

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, dependencies, testng

**Context**

I am writing unit tests using TestNG in Spring Tools Suite/Eclipse with the TestNG plugin for eclipse.  As part of one of these tests I am testing that the correct log output is being created using the slf4j-test library (https://projects.lidalia.org.uk/slf4j-test/)

The compatibility error encountered is:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in 
[jar:file:/C:/Users/****/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback- 
classic/1.2.3/logback-classic- 
1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in 
[jar:file:/C:/Users/****/.m2/repository/uk/org/lidalia/slf4j- 
test/1.1.0/slf4j-test-1.1.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an 
explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type 
[ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

In order to use this library, I need to exclude logback when I am running my tests due to known compatibility issues with the slf4j-test library.  I have done this by adding the following to my pom:

```
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <classpathDependencyExcludes>
              <classpathDependencyExcludes>ch.qos.logback:logback-classic</classpathDependencyExcludes>
            </classpathDependencyExcludes>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**Problem**

When I am running 'mvn test', all of the tests run fine and the exclusion happens as expected.  However, when I want to run an individual test using the TestNG plugin for eclipse (right click test class -> run as -> TestNG Test) so that I can see test results and coverage inside the IDE, the tests break because of the compatibility issue between the libraries.

**Question**

How can I exclude this dependency from the classpath the way that it is excluded from 'mvn test' when I want to run these tests individually using the TestNG plugin?